# Can a file be accessible on browser by ssh?

Tags: ssh, web

I know FTP works great, but setup FTP take some time; I wonder if there is any tool I can used to access Server file by SSH eg. ssh://root/filename.txt on the browser? (Browser is great, it supports all common files, including images, videos, audios and etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. SFTP does not work directly in browser. I think something that might be a better option for what you want is [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I guess FTP might be a better answer. I don't want to install anything :(~
But I still mark you as answer, and thanks for your response.